# Which latest django-storages and boto versions are compatible?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mod-wsgi, boto

I am using django-storages with boto for uploading and serving media files at amazon s3 buckets. When I try to do that from a development server, everything works fine.

But when I try to upload files on the public server with mod_wsgi, I get this error:

```
TypeError: set_contents_from_file() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rewind'
```

I checked `Key.set_contents_from_file()` and it has an argument `rewind`. What could be wrong?

I am using boto 2.18.0 and django-storages 1.1.5.

When I tried to upgrade boto to the latest 2.19.0 and django-storages to the latest 1.1.8, I got another error on the server with mod_wsgi:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: The installed Boto library must be 2.4 or higher.
See https://github.com/boto/boto
```

What are the correct versions working well with each other? Or what could be the reason of those errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was boto 2.3 installed to the global python dist-packages, which was for some reason used by mod_wsgi. Updating boto there with root permissions solved the problem.